# How to sort collection based on filed's which have unicode characters?

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala, I have to sort Seq[Country] based on country_name. Expected result should be:

```
    {
        "country_code": "AFG",
        "country_name": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
        "country_code": "ALA",
        "country_name": "Åland Islands"
    },
    {
        "country_code": "AGO",
        "country_name": "Angola"
    }
```

but I get below country at the end of the list using sortBy():

```
   {
        "country_code": "ALA",
        "country_name": "Åland Islands"
    }
```

Input list:

```
List(
    Country(AFG,Afghanistan),  
    Country(AGO,Angola), 
    Country(ALA,Åland Islands)
)
```

Below is the method:

```
 def sortCountry(sortIn: Seq[Country]): Seq[Country] = {
        val result: Seq[Country] =
          sortBy match {
            case "country_code" => sortIn.sortBy(_.country_code)
            case _ => sortIn.sortBy(_.country_name)
          }
          result
 }
```

Comment: Could you share your code snippet?

Comment: @Duelist included the snippet.

Comment: It would be better if you also share an input data. And what is `sortBy` value? Where is it from? Maybe it should be as method parameter?

Comment: There is no problem with your code. `Å` is not the same letter as `A`. https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00C5

Comment: My requirement says treat Å as A. In REPL: 

val ord = Ordering.comparatorToOrdering(Collator.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH))
Seq("a","b","c","ä","å").sorted(ord)

I get this response - 
scala> res10: Seq[String] = List(a, å, ä, b, c)

but i am not sure how would I do it Seq[Country]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sorted like this because `Å` and `A` are distinct letters. If you want to treat them as the same letter you can define a custom `Ordering` and sort like this:

```
case _ => sortIn.sortBy(_.country_name)(myCustomOrdering)
```

Comment: Thank you @Simon, It was a problem with myCustomOrdering. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for that answer for the benefit of the community here is how I achieved it, by using `implicit` param of `sortBy` function.

```
collection.sortBy(_.attributeName)(ord)   
val ord = Ordering
         .comparatorToOrdering(Collator.getInstance(Locale.getDefault))
         .asInstanceOf[Ordering[String]]
```